# Streaming an audio file in android via RTP

Tags: android, audio, stream, rtp

I am looking for a way to stream a prerecorded **MP3** or **WAV** file over the internet using `SIP` and `RTP`. The main stumbling block now has been how to get a `stream` from a file and `synchronize` it, so that it could be delivered via `RTP` just like a stream from **microphone** or **video camera**.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Did you have any update , I have the same problem...`Android` send `mp3` or `WAV` over `RTSP`. Is it must be convert the `mp3 or wav to AAC` ?

Comment: I converted it manually and streamed static data.